# Rack::SSL giving "ERROR bad Request-Line"

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rack::SSL in my Rails 3.1 application to enable SSL connections.

I've added `gem 'rack-ssl'` to my Gemfile and

```
require 'rack/ssl'
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::SSL, :exclude => proc { |env| env['HTTPS'] != 'on' }
```

to my environment configuration.

Accessing a resource over HTTP works fine, while using HTTPS for the same resource results in

```
[2012-02-04 02:18:32] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2012-02-04 02:18:35] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x01O,?m9?D??Puo'?w8r?U\x17RO?r????C?Q#\x00\x006?'.
[2012-02-04 02:18:35] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00A\x01\x00\x00=\x03\x00O,?mS67"?q???(T?27\x18B????C\x19?*B?\x00\x00\x16\x00/\x00\x05\x00\x04\x005\x00'.
[2012-02-04 02:18:37] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00A\x01\x00\x00=\x03\x00O,?oG\x18??%\eJ?n\x1Czt'V?5?B?3?1???Џ?\x00\x00\x16\x00/\x00\x05\x00\x04\x005\x00'.
[2012-02-04 02:18:38] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00A\x01\x00\x00=\x03\x00O,?p+EPU\x0F?\x00??/,?X?"@4}?ބE?c?o+?\x00\x00\x16\x00/\x00\x05\x00\x04\x005\x00'.
```

Any ideas what might cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're using the https protocol for a http connection.

Comment: The problem was that my webserver did not handle HTTPS requests correctly and passed them to the Rails application like HTTP requests.

Comment: @CodeBrickie, which webserver did you use? can you give any details on what you changed to webserver to have it pass https requests correctly to rails? I am running into same issue in my dev env using WEBrick. Thanks in adv.

Comment: @rafael I use WEBrick behind http://www.lighttpd.net as a reverse proxy. I could not get it to work with Apache so I switched over to lighttpd.